# Ember how to customise query parameter on model call

Tags: ember.js, ember-query-params

I'm passing parameter on model call like this

`app.store.find("post",{postNumber:[111,2]});`

the url for this call will be

`post?postNumber[]=111&postNumber[]=2`

but my need to have URL should be

`post?postNumber=111&postNumber=2`

Please tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Ember Data. Is that correct?

Comment: is this a valid query param? logically, it's always an empty set / false... `postNumber` can't equal `111` AND `2` at the same time, so it would rather consider changing the API

Comment: @Oren Yes I'm using ember data.

Comment: @andrusieczko This is correct param only. I have given sample parameter

Comment: if you want to achieve this, then you can extend the `DS.Adapter`, `findQuery` method. You can build your own `ajax` query in that method.

Comment: you were right by the way, it is a correct way of defining query params; I've checked it and when you pass `a=1&a=2`, on the server you get `{"a":["1","2"]}`, my bad

Comment: Are you in control of the API?

Comment: I have made query ajaxSettings.traditional = true;